# Should we add Entity Framework dll to all layers

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am writing a test app using EF code first. I have distributed code among different layers. I thought I would have to install the entity framework package to the data access layer only but what I ended up with is installing the package (adding dlls) to all the layers namely UI, BLL, Models, DAL. Is this okay or I am doing something wrong. Below is sample code to give you an idea of what I am trying to do

**Model Layer**

This layer is reference in all other layers/projects

```
namespace Model
{
   Public class Sample
   {
      [ForeignKey("Sample2Id")]
      ...

   }
}
```

In this layer I had to use Entity Framework dlls because of Data Annotation like `[ForeignKey..`

**DAL**

```
namespace DAL
{
   public class SampleContext:DbContext
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

In DAL I only have the context class and migrations

**BLL**

```
namespace BLL
{
   public class SampleBLL
   {
       public List<Sample> GetAll()
       {
          retrn new SampleContext().Samples().ToList()
       }
   }
}
```

If I uninstall EF for BLL I get the following error
The type System.Data.Entity.DbContext is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

**UI**

```
namespace UI
{
   public class UIHelper
   {
      public List<Sample> GetSamples()
      {
         return new SampleBLL().GetAll();
      }

   }
}
```

If I uninstall the EF package from UI I get the following error

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application

Comment: You have to install EF dll in all layers (which references it). I don't know why it is necessary. I hope we find someone that can explain.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample project which is quite similar to your current setup minus the Model Layer/DAL separation.

I have three projects, **DAL** (which contains references to the `EntityFramework.dll` and the `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`), **BLL** which just calls a method in the **DAL**, and the **UI** which just calls the **BLL** methods.

I had to add the `<configSections>`, the `<entityFramework>`, and the `<connectionStrings>` portions of the `app.config` of the **DAL** into the **UI's** `app.config`.

When I ran the code the first time, I ran into the same error you ran into. So I looked into the debug folder of my **UI** Project and noticed that the `EntityFramework.dll` was copied into the folder due to the **DAL's** dependency on it. I also noticed that the `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` was NOT copied into the debug folder despite the **DAL** also having a dependency on it.

I copied the `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` into the debug folder of the UI Project then re-ran the project then, Viola! My code ran as expected.

It looks like the problem here is that one dll is not being copied into the UI Project debug folder as it is expected to.